# Determine dimension of set of matrices given that each matrix has same eigenvalue 0 and eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let V be the set of all $A_{3×3}$ matrices, where all of them have eigenvalue 0 and corresponding eigenvector $y=(1,2,3)^T$.

Assuming we have showed that V is a vector space, determine the dimension of V.

---

From the definition we know that:
$x$ and $\lambda$ are eigenvector and eigenvalue iff $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ .

So for each matrix $A_i$ in our set$$
(A_i-0)
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
=0
$$
$$
A_i
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
=0
$$
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\in N(A_i)
$$
From this we find that $Nullity(A_i)\geq1 \Rightarrow $

$Rank(A_i) = n-Nullity(A_i)=3-1=2 \Rightarrow $

$Rank(A_i)=Dim(C(A_i)) \leq 2$

However, I am not sure how can I proceed from here?

1) How can determine the dimension of the matrix $A_i$ for sure?

2) How is that connected to the dimension of entire vector space formed by such matrices?